# Vector field along a parametrized curve and finding a variational vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I'm struggling to show this:

For all vector fields $ Y\in C^\infty_0([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n) $ along a parametrized curve $ \gamma_0:\ [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ there is a variation $ \gamma $ with variational vectorfield $ Y $.

$ C^\infty_0([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n):=\{Y:\ [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \text{smooth}|\exists \ \delta > 0 : Y_{|[a,a+\delta]\cup[b-\delta,b]}\equiv 0\} $

My idea:
Let $ Y\in C^\infty_0([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n) $ ba an arbitrary vector field along an arclenght-parametrizied curve $ \gamma_0:\ [0,L]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $. This means that for this vector field $ Y:\ [0,L]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ there is a $ \delta>0 $ with the property $ Y_{|[0,\delta]\cup[L-\delta,L]}\equiv 0\in \mathbb{R}^n $.
Define a curve $ \gamma: \ [0,L]\times ]-\varepsilon, \varepsilon[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $ \gamma(x,t)=\gamma_0(x) $ for all $ x\in [0,\delta]\cup[L-\delta,L] $. Then $ \gamma $ is a compactly supported variation of $ \gamma_0: \ x\mapsto \gamma(x,0) $.

From here I have no idea how to proceed. My first concept would be trying to extend my compactly supported variation to a variation of $ \gamma_0 $.

EDIT:
A $C^\infty$-Map $ \gamma: \ [a,b]\times ]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is called variation of the map $ \gamma_0: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $ \gamma(x,0)=\gamma_0(x) $ for all $ 
x\in [a,b] $.

Comment: How exactly are you defining $\gamma$?

Comment: $ \gamma: \ [a,b]\times ]-\varepsilon, \varepsilon[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is defined as a $C^\infty $-Map.

Comment: There are many such smooth maps. Which one is it? Once you have determined which one it is, then you can show that its variational field is $Y$.

Comment: What do you mean by "There are many such smooth maps."?

Comment: Literally what I said, there are lots of smooth maps from that domain to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that have $\gamma(t,0) = \gamma_0(t)$. Are you considering an arbitrary map? Are you going to pick a special one and show that its variation is $Y$?

Comment: This is kind of like trying to show that $x^2 = 4$ has a solution by starting with, "Define a number $x\in \mathbb{R}$..." You'll get stuck because you're reasoning about an arbitrary object in a class instead of finding or constructing the object in the class that meets your needs.

Comment: "Literally what I said, there are lots of smooth maps from that domain to Rn that have γ(t,0)=γ0(t). " And why??

Comment: "Are you considering an arbitrary map?" I consider an arbitrary vector field Y along a parametrized curve $ \gamma_0 $. Now I want to show that I can find a smooth function $ \gamma: \ [a,b]\times ]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ such that it is a variation of $ \gamma_0 $.